# Search and Replace Entire Project (Netbeans)

Tags: netbeans

Is there a way to do a project wide search and replace in netbeans? It seems like there should be, but I can not find any information on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Under the `Edit` menu you should find a menu item for `Replace in Projects...`

Comment: I figured you were having the same problem I have with Chrome. I don't know why their menu wording throws me off so much. Particularly the tab and link context menus. :)

Comment: Alas, this doesn't work for changing resource string identifiers - they get changed in .properties files and generated code in .java files, but not in the .form files from whence the generated code flows.

Comment: There seems to be a limit of 5000 for matching occurences. How do I increase it?

Answer (score 41):

If you click on the project in the projects pane.

Then press and hold **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>**

A find and replace window will come up where you can specify what you would like to find and what to replace it with. You can use regular expressions and then after you search you can walk through all the results in the different files that are returned.

Answer (score 16):

Go to `Edit` Menu -> you will find `Find in Projects` and `Replace in Projects` Option:

#### Shorcuts:

**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>** for Find in whole project.

**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>** for Replace in whole project.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make "Replace in Projects" search as offered by NetBeans, and operate in search results windows further on. There is a "replace" button in the icons strip on the left of the search windows; select all search results (or just some of them you feel appropriate) and click that icon.
You might have to wait a while if there are many files you are working with.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to find something and replace in the open file, you can do this:

Go to `Edit` Menu -> you will find `Replace` and below the editor will appear `Incremental Search Sidebar` where you can type what you need to find and replace.

#### Shorcuts:

**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>** for Find what and Replace with in the open file.