# Replace string in under a directory in netbeans

Tags: netbeans-7

I want to replace some strings in a particular directory in netbeans 7.3 
Is it possible?

mainly i need to replace 
'Notifynotify' string by
'Notify'

Comment: replaceAll() should be used

Answer (score 4):

In `NetBeans` press `CTRL + SHIFT + H` to open the Find and Replace option. There you can change any piece of text by another one, and in any folder / subfolder you want by changing the `Scope` parameter in the same window. You can select `Current project` (whole project), `Open projects`, An specific selection (If you highlight a package / folder in the project view) or a free browse option.

Answer in [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000376/search-and-replace-entire-project-netbeans?lq=1)

Comment: This is to replace in whole project. Right? I do not need it. I just want to replace in particular directory only.