# pdf to html conversion lacks single quotes

Tags: html

I have a PDF specification for building a html page. I used http://www.htmlpublish.com/convert-pdf-to-html/ to convert the pdf into the html I was otherwise going to have to write manually.

Unfortunately, the generated HTML has `colspan=4`,  when I would like `colspan='4'`  (the value should be surrounded by simple quotes).

What can I do to add the single quotes everywhere in the code where i have `colspan`? (appart from manually writing the quotes, because i have 704 colspans in my page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best answer I can give for this is to use a software which can replace the given value with what you have provided. So simply go for each separate `colspan='x'` values and you should be good to go with just few replacement commands.

**For example** you can search for that `colspan=4` and replace it with `colspan='4'`. Unfortunately you will have to do this with all the different values you have on your project file, but still this should be the best solution for mass-correcting such a thing.

Find and replace should be available for most of the commonly used software by built-in or as an addon.

See this question's answers for the solution in NetBeans software: [Search and Replace Entire Project (Netbeans)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000376/search-and-replace-entire-project-netbeans). As it is stated on the topic, this can find and replace lines project-wide, not only one file.

Comment: you are right . i should have thought about it. eclipse as well has such 'find and replace' features. And it supports regular expressions, too. However, I think this will be the topic of another question, which regex to be used so that I add single quotes, but keep the numeric value unchanged

Comment: and this is how it can be done in eclipse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30354041/eclipse-use-regex-with-find-replace-to-surround-numeric-values-with-single-quote