# eclipse use regex with find-replace to surround numeric values with single quotes

Tags: regex, eclipse

i have an html file opened with eclipse, and my intention is to replace `colspan=4` with `colspan='4'` . or, accordingly, replace `colspan=3` with `colspan='3'`. Can you help me with a suitable regular expression to be used with  'find and replace'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find: `colspan=(\d+)`
Replace: `colspan='\1'` or `colspan='$1'`

Note: When you enable regexp in the find dialog, you can get help by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd> in the find/replace text fields.