# Find and replace php <? short tags exclude xml and <?= in Netbeans

Tags: php, php-shorttags

I am working on an old project and found the previous developer has used `<?` all over the place.

I know how to search and replace all Literal occurrences but is there another way to find the exact matches?

This link only outlines how to do a search and replace but not a detailed search and replace -
[Search and Replace Entire Project (Netbeans)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000376/search-and-replace-entire-project-netbeans)

Is there a **regex** or something I can use to replace every `<?` occurance and exclude any `<?=` , `<?php` , `<?=` or `<?xml`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search and Replace Entire Project (Netbeans)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000376/search-and-replace-entire-project-netbeans)

Comment: Thanks for the sugeestion but I know how to basically use that feature. I want a more robust solution though. Please re-read OP

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of that page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try TextCrawler (http://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/textcrawler.html) program, which support regex for find and replace. Use this regexp:

```
\<\?[^=|xml|php]
```

And replace it with `<?php`

Comment: Replace it with <?php and space

Answer (score 1):

Comming from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000376/search-and-replace-entire-project-netbeans): Under the Edit menu you should find a menu item for Replace in Projects...

Comment: The above link only outlines how to search and replace which I already know how to do. Thanks