# Is it possible to change entire css class / js and anything associate with that?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am new here.
Just want to ask several question to anyone experienced in this field.

So I have just bought a php website, and the case is that the owner of this theme seems a bit strict with copyright stuff, so he placed his own identity in almost every way.

In example, the website named "mcdonalds", he have almost in his entire css class after his name/brand, example .mcdonalds_header , or .mcdonalds_style.css , etc .

Now my question is,

**Is it possible to change entire css class dynamically?**

I meant, if I open it through text editor maybe I could replace them all by hitting Ctrl+H and replace "mcdonalds_" with [nothing].But of course it will return many errors as the entire php and js file are associated with those class.

What I want in example I have

index.php with 8 div have class "mcdonalds_grid"
style.css file with class "mcdonalds_grid"

is it possible to edit the class in css "mcdonalds_grid" to "gridStyle", and then the entire 8 class in the file changed automatically, too?

Because I am not sure to do it manually. In my case I have up to hundred thousands to be edited. It sicks. And if you asked the reason I need to do this, so it looks more professional using my own brand rather than using mcdonald's stuffs.

Any view would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: add or remove css classes with jQuery:
[add class](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_addclass.asp) 
-
[remove class](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_removeclass.asp)

Comment: `something_class` Using `something_` before the class name/function name etc is called prefix. When people create something and target  to sell  in marketplace, they use prefix not only for branding. The big reason is if you use 3rd party plugins there might be some conflict between main websites function/class with the plugins function/class which might show some errors. To make the functions/classes unique, they use a prefix. So, I will suggest you not to remove the prefixes unless those hamper your work.

Comment: Then instead of removing `something_` , I would prefer change to `somethingofmyown_` so neither it will make conflict nor branding .. And how I accomplish that? @MeFaysal

Comment: I never heard of any automated process to do this. Experts might have some better idea/suggestion, you may wait for more answers but you can check the following link to replace something in the whole project using NetBeans. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000376/search-and-replace-entire-project-netbeans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Others have mentioned Jquery.

You could also do it dynamically with Less Mixins: https://www.gaslampmedia.com/mapping-css-styles-less/.

Or you could do it non-dynamically (I would recommend this).  You could use an IDE (Integrated Development Environment) or an advanced text editor to search and replace all instances of a text string in the entire project at once.  In your case, you could replace all instances of mcdonald with the name of your company or project.  Advanced Text Editors like Sublime Text or Notepad++ could let you do this, but you would generally need to open all of the files at once.  IDEs like Visual Studio or Dreamweaver would also let you do this, with the benefit of not having to open all of the files (you just add the files to your project).

Comment: Wow such a great idea! But one more question. I am afraid that they are using this also for database.. Does this method will harm the code for overall? I have 0 experience in database scripting. Does database are connected to website through PHP ? If so, change php file `something.php` to `somethingmyown.php` would make this an error, right? @Timothy

Comment: No they are not connected like this.  In every situation I've ever seen, PHP pages have a dependence on the database, and not vice versa.  In other words, nowhere in your database will your PHP pages be mentioned.  Just make a complete copy of the website and apply the replace to the COPY only, keeping the original intact.  Then if it breaks, you'll have the old code still working.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't suggest to make these types of edit but if you must need to do then follow the process:

> From the answer of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000376/search-and-replace-entire-project-netbeans)

You can use IDE to change something in the whole project. I would suggest NetBeans. It's easy. Just add the project to NetBeans, click on edit (in the top left corner) and then click on Replace in project.. ( check in the bottom of the popup)

[image]

then

[image]