# How do I get a red box to appear outside of a variable name, to change it in all of the places i'm using it in java netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts, settings

I'm talking about boxes like these:

[image]

Comment: have you tried to search with ctrl+f?

Comment: What do you mean by "outside of a variable name"?

Comment: this should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000376/search-and-replace-entire-project-netbeans

Comment: I'm asking if there's a shortcut which can be used in NetBeans to change all variables which have the same name at once so that you don't have to change all of their names individually.

Comment: Yep, i misunderstood, blame on me, but as @BenSch suggest, this looks like a duplicate ? ^^

Comment: @Curtis.T once you are inside one of the red boxes, just type a new name and it will change in all the other red boxes too.

Comment: You're looking for the shortcut for the Rename refactoring. Ctrl-R. http://www.codejava.net/ides/netbeans/10-netbeans-shortcut-keys-for-code-refactoring

Comment: CTRL+R.......,,

Comment: Did you consider trying to have a look at [Highlights of NetBeans IDE 8.0 Keyboard Shortcuts & Code Templates](https://netbeans.org/project_downloads/usersguide/shortcuts-80.pdf)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to do this:

> Right click variable name -> Refactor -> Rename

A red box will outline that variable everywhere it is used and rename it to what you enter.

As a shortcut to answer the OP's question, click the variable name and use

> CTRL + R

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll use this

Comment: Thanks @Curtis.T if you caan accept and upvote my answer if it helps you, it will be much appreciated.